# what is the meaning for . (dot) before the target in makefile

Tags: makefile

In a  make file i found the code snip like below. Is there any difference between create_file and run_debug ? i mean the use of . (dot) before create_file introduce any functionality like PHONY?

```
all:debug run_debug
setup: .create_file

.create_file:
      cd /home/user1
      touch file.txt

 run_debug:
      @echo Building debug
      cd /home/user1/debug
```

Comment: There is one difference I know: target names that start with a period are not considered when make identifies the default goal (the one that is done when you simply call `make`), unless they also contain slashes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As far as I know it has only one purpose (and in this makefile that purpose is obviated by the makefile construction).

From [How `make` Processes a Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#How-Make-Works):

> By default, `make` starts with the first target (not targets whose names start with `‘.’`). This is called the *default goal*.

So a leading `.` means that make will not consider that target as a valid default goal.

But, as written, the `all` target is the first target in this makefile so that will be the default goal so the leading dot here doesn't actually do anything.

That said all three of the `setup`, `run_debug` and `.create_file` targets should be marked as `.PHONY` and may have much better ways of being written/etc.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the *default goal* use, I also found it convenient that targets beginning with a `.` are not displayed in auto-completion, i.e. typing `make`  + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

So I prefix targets that are not meant for the end user with a `.`

Comment: Same goes for `_`