# What's the meaning of targets in a Makefile that start with a ., and how is it different/similar to suffix rules?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In a Makefile, I saw this:

```
all: .made

# ... some other code

.made: $(Program) bashbug
    @echo "$(Program) last made for a $(Machine) running $(OS)" >.made
```

Is the `.made` rule a suffix rule as per: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules?

Also, are all rules with targets that have a `.` in front suffix rules?

Otherwise, what is the significance of targets that start with .? It seems like there's a significance as per this in https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#How-Make-Works:

> By default, make starts with the first target (not targets whose names
>   start with ‘.’).

But its significance is not mentioned.

Also, if it is a suffix rule, how come `.made` can be used as a prerequisite in the all rule? (It's not mentioned that the targets of suffix rules can be used as prerequisites in other rules.)

P.S.: This question is related to but different from [what is the meaning for . (dot) before the target in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480480/what-is-the-meaning-for-dot-before-the-target-in-makefile). This question asks explicitly for the difference between a target with . and a target of a suffix rule.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the meaning for . (dot) before the target in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480480/what-is-the-meaning-for-dot-before-the-target-in-makefile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the `.made` rule a suffix rule

No, because `.made` is not a "known suffix".

> Also, are all rules with targets that have a `.` in front suffix rules?

No, only those where the word after the dot is a "known suffix":

Your first two questions are answered by https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules:

> Suffix rule definitions are recognized by comparing each rule’s target against a defined list of known suffixes. When `make` sees a rule whose target is a known suffix, this rule is considered a single-suffix rule. When `make` sees a rule whose target is two known suffixes concatenated, this rule is taken as a double-suffix rule.

In your example `.made` is an actual filename. Your Makefile has a rule for it that creates/updates the file:

```
#vvvv
.made: $(Program) bashbug
        @echo "$(Program) last made for a $(Machine) running $(OS)" >.made
#                                                                    ^^^^^
```

All pretty normal; it would work the same way with any other name.

The only significance of the leading dot is that it makes the file "hidden" by convention, i.e. `ls` won't show it (without specifying `-a`), plain `*` won't match it, etc.